# How to make custom type handler available globally for specific datatype in mybatis

Tags: java, oracle, timestamp, mybatis, typehandler

I am using Mybatis 3.2.2. While inserting data dynamically in Oracle I am facing an issue with Timestamp datatype. So I have written custom type handler for TimeStamp.
Now for any query whenever Timestamp datatype comes into picture I want to give the call to this custom typeHandler not default one.

But somehow my typeHandler is not visible globally to take up. Mybatis is calling default typeHandler.

I have written below annotation above custom typeHandler

```
@MappedJdbcTypes(JdbcType.VARCHAR)
@MappedType(value=Timestamp.class)
```

In mybatis configuration file

```
<typeHandlers>
  <typeHandler handler="com.corp.mapper.TimestampTypeHandler"/>
</typeHandlers>
```

Please let me know what I am missing.

Comment: Try removing `@MappedJdbcType`.

Comment: @ave it didn't work

Comment: Then please create a small project like [these](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues) and share it on your GitHub repo.

Comment: @ave Before that I just want to know is it possible in mybatis 3.2.2 to make custom typeHandler global and not query specific? 
Like whenever column type occurred as a Timestamp it should automatically call to custom typeHandler and not mybatis's default one.

Comment: Your explanation is not very clear. If you mean Java type `java.sql.Timestamp`, it would be possible. If you mean column data type `TIMESTAMP`, you might need to specify `jdbcType` or `typeHandler` in the parameter reference of INSERT statement, but not in the result map. All these ambiguity will be cleared up if you provide an executable project. And 3.2.2. is super old. You should use newer version (3.5.6 is the latest).

Comment: Correct. 
You understood right. 
But my INSERT query is dynamic so I won't be able to provide jdbcType or typeHandler explicitly. 
Whenever column of datatype TIMESTAMP will come I need my typeHandler get called automatically.

Yes I went through mybatis documentation it said that 3.5.6 will resolve DATE and TIMESTAMP issues but due to some reasons we are not able to upgrade right now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230028/discussion-between-ave-and-rujuta-s).